# Linear regression with polynimial features

Tags: python, linear-regression

i have built this model for the dataset Concrete Compressive Strength.

````
X_train_new, X_test_new, Y_train_new, Y_test_new = train_test_split(new_X, Y, test_size=0.3, shuffle='False')

   new_X = pd.concat((X**(i+1) for i in range(n)), axis=1)
    colnames=[]

    for j in range(8*n):                                      
        colnames.append(j)

    new_X.columns = colnames

    X_train_new_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train_new)
    X_test_new_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test_new)

    ols.fit(X_train_new_scaled, Y_train)
    poly_train_pred = ols.predict(X_train_new_scaled)
    poly_test_pred = ols.predict(X_test_new_scaled)
    poly_mae_train_error = metrics.mean_absolute_error(Y_train_new, poly_train_pred)
    poly_mae_test_error = metrics.mean_absolute_error(Y_test_new, poly_test_pred)
    print(poly_mae_train_error, "\n", poly_mae_test_error)```
````

8 is the number of the features.
ols is a LinearRegression class that i created earlier.

Is it ok that the `test_error` of the this model is higher than the one of the simple linear model?
Also how i implement the fucntion `test_poly_regression(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, n=2)` to run this model for multiple n and check the errors?

Comment: hi, have you ever heard of minimal working example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example